# Icon font background on hover

Tags: css, background, hover, icon-fonts

In the footer of my site http://www.stefaanoyen.be (left column) I have some social media icons which are an icon font. On hover, I want the circles red and the icons in it white. The red circles work, but there's a white square behind them. How do I limit the white to the shape of the icons/circles?

This is my HTLM:

```
<p class="share"><a href="#">l</a> <a href="#">i</a> <a href="#">g</a> <a href="#">f</a></p>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.share a {
color: #ececec;
text-decoration: none;
font: 50px 'socialicoregular', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.share:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.share a:hover {
color: #B61618;
text-decoration: none;
font: 50px 'socialicoregular', Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Stefaan

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for this one because you only rely on a font. You could try to add a `border-radius` (your `font-size` is set to 50px so radius of 25px will probably do it but you will have to play around with it) to the `.share a:hover` element.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this, but it still shows a white edge around the red circle... Tried with `background-size: 25px 25px` but that didn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `background-image` (a white circle width the right dimensions) on the `.share a:hover`

Answer (score 0):

The "Shape of the icons/circles" is actually a rectangle.
You're setting the white background to the link. The link is a rectangle.
You won't be able to directly style the background of a font/character.

Since your icons are all rounded, here's a little trick you could use:

```
border-radius: 50px;
```

That's simply a guessed figure. It doesn't mean it's the right one. Just find the one you need that matches your icons height/width. 
(You might also need to work with your line-height to make sure your font is, or at least looks vertically centered.)

Comment: ..of course, this won't work in browsers that don't support border-radius: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: Or, you can use `border-radius: 50%` :)

Comment: Even better. Thanks, @Terry

Comment: Thanks! See my comment below, any ideas?